# Frequency table with disorganized datas made by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have an excel archive with different numbers and i open it using pandas.
when i read and then print the xslx archive ,i have something like this:

```
    5    7    7    
0   6    16   5    
1   10   12   15   
2   1    5    6    
3   5    6    18   
.   .    .    .    
.   .    .    .    
n   .    .    n
```

All i need is to distribute them with different intervals according to their frequencies.

my code is

```
import pandas as pd
excel_archive=pd.read_exceL("file name")
print(excel)
```

Comment: Please provide your expected output also?

Comment: i expect a frequencies distribution table like this one:
https://gradeup-question-images.grdp.co/liveData/PROJ16510/1526637505744790.png

Comment: What do the rows and columns signify in your data? Do we only care about how many times `12` appears in the table, or do we also care about which rows or which columns it appears in?

Comment: the collumns doesnt mean anythig, we only care about how many times 12 apears in the table

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but if you just have to count the number of occurrence you can try something like this:

```
#generate a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9], [1, 5, 2], [7, 9, 9]]),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

#Flatten the array
df_flat=df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

#Count the number of occurences
df_flat.groupby(df_flat).size()
```

This is the input:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  4
2  7  8  9
3  1  5  2
4  7  9  9
```

And this is the output:

```
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    2
7    2
8    1
9    3
```

If you want instead to divide in some predefined intervals you can use `pd.cut` together with `groupby`:

```
#define intervals
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays([0,3,6],[3,6,9],closed='right')
#cut and groupby
df_flat.groupby(pd.cut(df_flat,intervals)).size()
```

and the result would be:

```
(0, 3]    5
(3, 6]    4
(6, 9]    6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think excel file has no header, so first add `header=None` to [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and then use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
excel_archive=pd.read_exceL("file name", header=None)
s = excel_archive.stack().value_counts()
print (s)
5     4
6     3
7     2
15    1
12    1
10    1
18    1
1     1
16    1
dtype: int64
```